# How does Crittercism of Apteligent gather breadcrumbs in android

Tags: java, android, crittercism

I had integrated crittercism inside my application. All I was needed while integrating was to initialise it inside my custom application class. I was wondering how does crittercism tracks my breadcrumbs which includes all the network calls I make. Including the calls to any 3rd party or API calls or logging events. All are tracked by the crittercism. How is crittercism able to do this without overriding any classes.

I am not using any other implementations mentioned in the doc. Just simple initialisation but on the dashboard I am getting something like this : 
[image]

Here you can see the network details are logged. I want to know what coding hack are they using in Java to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the initialization can be done by specifying one line and it will make the crash reporting work, however, to log custom breadcrumbs and other data like Network Inights, Userflows, User Metadata for Android, you are supposed to make some additional modifications to your project, you can refer to the official docs of Apteligent where things are well explained.

https://docs.apteligent.com/android/android.html

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for describing your question. The breadcrumbs you are showing in the screenshots are the automatic ones which don't require any extra code implementation like I mentioned in my previous post. You may also disable these automatic breadcrumbs by mentioning setServiceMonitoringEnabled(false) in CrittercismConfig file as shown below :-

```
CrittercismConfig config = new CrittercismConfig();
config.setServiceMonitoringEnabled(false);
Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), “CRITTERCISM_APP_ID”, config);
```

Comment: Thanks but I understand all this. My question is HOW crittercism is able track my network calls. I mean how its sdk is able to do this. They cant be using reflection or custom class loading as I am using OkHTTP and not the java http client. My querry is how is the sdk able to do this.